# How to delete an island in NetCDF file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf, climate-data-operators

I have a NetCDFf file (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10XvLZPC9vX9odkfU6aV6qBIxRe9IQvyZ?usp=sharing)

The variable in the plot below is inside yelmo2d.nc --> z_srf

The file contains height of the Greenland ice sheet.

[image]

What I want to do is delete the island on the upper left part using QGIS or any other methods while maintaining the coordinates xc and yc (Cartesian coordinates) and leaving the main island of Greenland only.

Any idea on how to do this?